# Python 3 pyodbc stored procedure not fully executing

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I'm working on a script for a monthly file load that requires the use of a stored procedure in our MS SQL database.

When I call the stored procedure via pyodbc, it starts executing, but it never finishes. My pseudocode is as follows:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute({'call stored_procedure'})
cursor.commit()

for n in range(1, 103):
    c2 = db.cursor()
    c2.execute('select IsFinished from '
               'procedure_statuses where '
               'procedure_name = "stored_procedure"')
    r = c2.fetchone()
    if r == True:
        c2.close()
        break
    c2.close()
    time.sleep(300)
cursor.close()
```

procedure_status's StartDate is always changed at the beginning of the run, but the IsFinished is never changed and neither is the FinishedDate. These fields are all updated in the stored procedure, like so

```
update procedure statuses
    set IsFinished = 0, StartDate = GETDATE()
    where procedure_name = 'stored_procedure'

/* TONS OF STORED PROCEDURE */

update procedure_statuses
    set IsFinished = 1, FinishedDate = GETDATE()
    where procedure_name = 'stored_procedure'

return
```

I'm noticing that there is a process existing for the second cursor (the "select IsFinished" bit) but not for the first one in the Activity Monitor.

So, why is pyodbc starting the stored procedure but not finishing it?

*EDIT: It should be noted, as well, that this is a fairly large stored procedure.  The execution time inside of MSSQL Server can last over 15 minutes. If this is a common problem with large stored procedures I'm really screwed because I have another one that can take a few hours that I need to trigger.

Comment: SSIS seems like a better way to run monthly stored procedures rather than writing a python program to run a cursor to run a sproc to run a cursor to update a table with the sproc statuses...

Comment: @JacobH the script does not only execute stored procedures, it also has a myriad of other functionalities that I&#39;m not comfortable trying to replicate in SQL like file conversions. I&#39;ll look into it, though and if it seems like I&#39;ll finish faster in pure SQL I could do that. Also, I'd never even heard of SSIS until I read your comment, so thanks for setting me off in a general direction. It's better than what I already had.